# String.replace() in case of different encodings

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, replace, aws-lambda

When I use `JSON.stringfy().replace(/[\t\r\n]/g,"").trim()` on response messages (lambda functions callbacks) from different system I face an issue where `\t` will be replaced with `\\t` and `\` to `\\\`

Is there a way to avoid this?

I tried to search for answers but only found articles for base cases.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) Requests for articles are off-topic, so I've removed that from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify`'s specific purpose is to convert what you give it to JSON. If what you give it is a string with backslashes in it, then what you'll get back is the JSON representation of that string, which is the string encased in double quotes (`"`) with any special characters, such as backslashes, escaped with a backslash, newlines converted to `\n`, carriage returns converted to `\r`, etc.

Example:

```js
const str = document.querySelector("input").value;
console.log("The string:", str);
console.log("JSON.stringify's output:", JSON.stringify(str));
```

```html
<input type="text" value="This string has a backslash in it: \ For instance, here's a backslash followed by a t: \t">
```

That's what `JSON.stringify` does. If you don't want that, don't use `JSON.stringify`.

---

> ...in case of different encodings

That part is irrelevant. By the time you're dealing with a JavaScript string, it doesn't matter what encoding was used to represent that string (in an HTML file, a `.js` file, etc.). Once it's in memory, it's in the one format for JavaScript strings defined by the language (which is [essentially UTF-16](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-string-value), except invalid surrogate pairs are allowed).